# What are the values of these 2 resistors?

Tags: resistors, identification, component-values

What are the values of the two highlighted resistors?

Considering the brown band as tolerance and ignoring the first (black) band, I came to the conclusion that the values are 680 and 220 milliohms. Is that correct? Thanks.

[image: Photo of PCB with two resistors highlighted]

Comment: 0.68 and 0.11 more like. Unless you see red when I see brown.

Comment: `I came to the conclusion that the values are 680 and 220 milliohms. Is that correct?` correct. @AndyAka the one to the right has red stripes. At least my smartphone and PC monitor shows so.

Comment: I homed in and it looked more red than brown then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.68\$\Omega\$  +/-1%  and 0.22\$\Omega\$ +/-1%

Probably both 1/4-W.